Sockets in POSIX RT PSE profiles
I stumbled upon the API standards for open systems. In Appendix A., at the end of this document there is a Feature Matrix which summarizes the requirements for key profiles.
Regarding the Feature "Sockets", can someone explain to me why they are not included into the PSE profiles since they are part of the (local) Inter-process communications when it comes to the Unix Domain Socket where the sockets address is a /path/filename identifier. Why do we then see other Inter-process communication mechanisms included into the PSE profiles(51, 52, 53 and 54) ? Do they mean with "Sockets" Internet Domain Sockets then ?
regards
